# Ubuntu 14.04 tls login

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have an issue with my Ubuntu 14.04 TLS.

Yesterday I installed service vnc4server to my ubuntu.

All works correctly until I close session.

Now, I can't login with account amaluquer, but yes with other accounts.

I show you a [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk4rz.gif) with issue I've: I log in to account, and it "refresh" and close session.

I tried uninstall service vnc4server, but issue persist.

I can login as root and access to terminal.

You know how fix issue with my username amaluquer?

Comment: This is blatantly off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are on login screen press "Ctrl + Alt + F1".

On console login with credentials are damaged. In you case, amaluquer and her password.

Use the next commands:
1> **mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak**
2> **exit**

After that, press "Ctrl + Alt + F7" and try login.